# How more effectively find the substrings between the separator in PL/SQL?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

Now I do this:

```
declare
    str varchar2(1000) := '1a2b3c / a1b2c3';
begin
    dbms_output.enable;
    dbms_output.put_line( regexp_replace(str, '(.*) / .*', '\1') );--1a2b3c 
    dbms_output.put_line( regexp_replace(str, '.* / (.*)', '\1') );--a1b2c3
end;
```

How can I in a different way do this?

How can I do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

Use `INSTR()` and look for a `/`:

```
DECLARE
    str varchar2(1000) := '1a2b3c / a1b2c3';
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( TRIM( SUBSTR(str, 1, INSTR(str, '/') - 1) ) );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( TRIM( SUBSTR(str, INSTR(str, '/') + 1, LENGTH(str) - INSTR(str, '/')) ) );
END;
```

You could also use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`, but if you don't want to use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` you probably don't want to use regular expressions at all:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( TRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '^[^\/]*') ) );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( TRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^\/]*$') ) );
```

Comment: Yes, this does look more efficient, though the parenthesis do not match up (1 short) for both of your calls to dbms_output.put_line (in your first approach).

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression:

```
WITH s AS (SELECT '1a2b3c / a1b2c3' txt, '[^/]+' regexp FROM DUAL)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (txt,
                      regexp,
                      1,
                      LEVEL)
  FROM s
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (txt,
                          regexp,
                          1,
                          LEVEL)
             IS NOT NULL;
```